# Detecting mouse clicks in terminal emulator w/o breaking scrolling

Tags: mouseevent, mouse, mousewheel, xterm, terminal-emulator

Using XTERM control sequences (specifically `CSI ?1000h`), I can get notified on stdin any time the user clicks on the terminal window. Unfortunately this also means I get notified if the scroll wheel is spun, instead of normal terminal scrolling taking place. Is there any way to, preferably easily and simply, **just** get notified about clicks and nothing else?

Alternatively, is there a way to send an escape sequence that the terminal emulator will interpret as "oh, you want me to scroll normally"? I'd be (reluctantly) okay with having to parse all the mouse commands, and then if I notice a scroll-up signal (button 96 or 64 depending on mode), echo it back saying "here, terminal, you handle this one". In theory these should be the `scroll-forw` and `scroll-back` actions, but I haven't found a way to use these directly.

If it makes any difference, I'm using xfce4-terminal, but am willing to try other terminal emulators if it would help with debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

The [X10 protocol](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-X10-compatibility-mode) sends *only clicks* (no wheel mouse). That's documented. But that's for xterm.

VTE (checking just now with XFCE Terminal) differs from xterm by sending wheel-mouse events.  VTE has no documentation worth mentioning, aside from its source-code (*[ymmv](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiU5qeZyJ7oAhXJlXIEHW2BB_wQFjABegQIDBAF&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdictionary.cambridge.org%2Fus%2Fdictionary%2Fenglish%2Fymmv&usg=AOvVaw3xMq1bRXa01KQbQKks-0oV)*).

The [*scroll-forw*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Actions:scroll-forw) and [*scroll-back*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Actions:scroll-back) actions are xterm features, for which there are no counterparts in VTE.

Comment: Yeah, X10 has no wheel support, but if you activate some of the other modes, you can respond to wheel events. `less(1)` does this, and it handles its own scrolling. I don't want to do that - I want the normal scrolling to happen as normal.